# How to fix: Importing error: cannot import name?

Tags: python, antspyx

I have the following code:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy
import pathlib
from ants import image_read, resample_image, iMath, from_numpy, threshold_image, copy_image_info, image_write
from copy import copy
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import backend as K
import timeit
```

On line 5, I get an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'image_read' from 'ants'`. Why does this occur? How can I fix the `ImportError`?

Comment: Did you install the package `ANTsPy` using `pip install antspyx` in your project environment?

Comment: Yes, I did. So I am unsure why it is causing me this issue

Comment: Show the full traceback. Do you have a local file called `ants.py` lying around?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try [reading the documentation](https://antspyx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest)? In your own words, why do you expect `from ants import image_read` to work? I mean - why should there be an `image_read` contained in `ants` - according to what source? If you saw some existing code that uses this library, did you try to check how *that* code gets access to `image_read`?

Comment: "Does anyone know a good solution for this problem? All suggestions are appreciated and helpful!" Please read [ask] and note that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are looking for a *specific question*; a call for suggestions [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Better: "Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?"